# How to store a dictionary with strings and numbers in a hdf5 file?

Tags: python, hdf5

Good evening,

I am trying to store a dictionary with strings and numbers in an hdf5 file, but not successfully. I have already stored some datasets with numpy but only with numbers!I have made a research but I can't find a tutorial or something like this.

Thank you very much for your time in advance

Comment: Can you present in a schematic and explicit way what is your data structure and what your needs in terms of size (100 entries, a million?)?

Comment: @ Pierre de Buyl it is not a big dictionary because I am new in python and I am just practicing and trying to execute some exercises and some codes on my own. So my dictionary is a part of an exercise I made and it stores only 5 entries. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The following code saves a dict with some strings and numbers to a hdf5 file.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

# Write
dic = {'a': 'astring',
       'b': np.arange(10),
       'c': 15}
path = 'item/'
with h5py.File('test.h5', 'w') as h5file:
    for key, item in dic.items():
        # note that not all variable types are supported but string and int are
        h5file[path + key] = item

# Read
file = h5py.File('test.h5', 'r')
item = file['item']
keys = item.keys()
out_dict = {}
for key in keys:
    out_dict[key] = item[key][()]
```

This code is based on [this stackexchange post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120802/recursively-save-python-dictionaries-to-hdf5-files-using-h5py/121308). The code in that post makes it possible to store dicts in dicts hierarchically.

Naturally JSON is a very nice hierarchical file format as well, but hdf5 was developed with incremental load/save in mind, which makes it more suitable for my current project.